# Examples of conjectural functorial transfer which has $\times GL(1)$ functional equation?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions, langlands-conjectures

I am look for some conjectural functorial transfer $X$ which

(A)for any $GL(1)$ automorphic representation $\pi$, we have 
$L(s, X\times \pi)$ is holomorphic and satisfies certain functional equation.

(B)$X$ is not yet known to be an automorphic representation.

At this moment, the only example I have for $X$ is $\Pi_1\times \tilde\Pi_2$, 
where $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ are two automorphic representation on $GL(m_1)$ and $GL(m_2)$ respectively, with $(m_1,m_2)\neq (2,2), (2,3) \text{ or }(3,2)$.

My question: is there anything else (maybe symmetric $x^{th}$ power lift of GL(2)?)?